# change dataframe values into np.nan using apply returns 0.0

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, numpy, nan

This is my code where `this_proteinDF.loc[:, 'p-value']` contains masked values:

```
this_proteinDF.loc[:, 'p-value'] = this_proteinDF.loc[:, 'p-value'].apply(lambda x: np.nan if x is np.ma.masked else x)
```

This should change every masked value into `np.nan`, however when I call the values after this operation it returns a float64 `0.0` instead of `nan`.

What's going on here and how do i fix this?

Answer (score 0):

It seems you have several points of mis-understanding (you and me).

1. `np.ma.masked` is a `numpy` constant that supposed to mean that something is masked.  I do not think it means what you think it means.
2. I'm not sure when you actually want the `'p-value'` series masked.

I'm thinking it's beneficial to you and maybe others to show the following.

***`mask` method***
use `pandas` to mask the things you'd like

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'p-value': [.001, .01, .1, .2, .05, .5]})
df
```

[image]

Check what's not significant

```
df['p-value'].gt(.05)

0    False
1    False
2     True
3     True
4    False
5     True
Name: p-value, dtype: bool
```

`mask` will make `True` values into `np.nan` values

```
df.loc[:, 'is_sig'] = df['p-value'].mask(df['p-value'].gt(.05))
df
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I actually have `masked` values in my dataframe (value = `ma.masked`). I want to change these values into `np.nan`. If you want to know how I actually got those masked values: they were returned to me like that by `scipy.stats.ttest_ind()`. When I write the masked values to disk and then read that file again, the `masked` values are shown as "--" instead of other, real `nan` values which are shown as "nan". Obviously I would like both to be equal to "nan".
By the way, I don't want anything to ever be masked. It is just a by-product of `ttest_ind`
Any further ideas?